Why does Item Response Theory not depend on a representative sample, or why is it "sample-independent"?
Multiple resources describing Item Response Theory (IRT) and comparing it to Classical Test Theory (CTT) note that CTT depends on a representative sample whereas IRT does not.

Sample-independence of scale: Classical statistics are all sample dependent, and unusable on a different sample; results from IRT are sample-independent. within a linear transformation.  Two samples of different ability levels can be easily converted onto the same scale.
Item properties don't depend on a representative sample.


These resources seem to state this as a factual distinction between the two theories and modeling approaches, but I do not understand why this is necessarily true. Is it not the case that item parameters can vary differently between populations? Is the point of this claim that if Differential Item Functioning (DIF) is not occurring, than you can say with some confidence that it does not depend on the representative samples? However, if this is the explanation for that bullet, I still do not understand as CTT (i.e., SEM, CFA) also involve tests for measurement invariance.
Can someone help me understand why IRT does not depend on representative sample or is "sample-independent"?
Resources:
https://www.publichealth.columbia.edu/research/population-health-methods/item-response-theory
https://assess.com/what-is-item-response-theory/

The cited list has some rather general statements, with many underlying assumptions, which in many practical applications will not be met. I disagree with the last bullet point for CTT.
IRT is just as "sample independent" as factor analysis. There is no real distinction between the two, most differences are historical, and relate to different estimators and parameterizations being used. But in general, all factor models can be written as IRT models, vice vera.
In CTT, the true score is not necessarily unidimensional. This sets it apart from factor analysis and IRT.
Item properties in IRT do not depend on the sample, as long as the unidimensionality and thereby conditional independence assumption is not violated. DIF is a violation of conditional independence, and makes item parameters dependent on the sample. However, because of the unidimensionality and conditional independence assumptions of IRT, we could still incorporate additional covariates (e.g., subgroup memberships) in the model. This would in many cases not make it IRT or unidimensional anymore, but would allow for distinguishing effects of the latent trait(s) and the covariate(s). It would not solve the issue of item parameters being sample dependent, but provides fruitful ways to account for it.
In CTT, this would be much more difficult. The elegance of the true and test score in CTT is that it need not be unidimensional (which few if any constructs of interest in the real world are). Yet, this makes it very difficult, if not impossible, to distinguish effects of items and samples, because anything that varies in a systematic manner will likely be absorbed by the true score, which thereby becomes an aggregate of item and sample properties. Latent traits in IRT and factor anaysis suffer less from this problem, because they are unidimensional (even if there are multiple (correlated) latent traits, each one of them still is unidimensional).
In response to the comments by AdamO, in the absence of DIF, the CTT assumption of the standard error of measurement being constant for all levels of the true score is probably invalid for many tests. In IRT, it is given by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(I(\theta))}}$, where $I$ is the test information, which varies as a function of the latent trait. This can, for example, result in more valid confidence intervals and thereby comparisons between persons using IRT, compared to using CTT.

If there is no DIF, it would be useful to explain the conditions that IRT leads to valid analysis when classical test theory might not.
